# C++ library related queries

Tags: c++

What does the inside of a library look like?

Are the different function codes just stored in there in different blocks one after another like in a C++ program as follows?

```
function1_name (argument_1, argument_2)
{
//function_1 code
} 

function2_name (argument_1)
{
//function_2 code
}
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Library files do not contain source code. They contain compiled ubject files, along with information as to where those object files are located in the library that is used by a linker later to be able to locate and use them when building executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An executable is something that can be run directly and it can contain many functions in it, but one of them is the "entry point". We can see the entry point as the function that it is first run (there are a few things that can run before - read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/executing-main-in-c-behind-the-scene/) for more info). In C/C++ the entry point is the `main` function.

On the other hand, a library is not run directly and instead, it provides functions (or classes, etc) that can be called from other libraries or from the executable. In C/C++ a library will not have a `main` function, since otherwise when the executable is linked with the library you would get multiple definitions for the `main` function.

Besides this, there is not much difference between an executable and a library and how they "look inside" will depend on the format. A python library is just another text file with a bunch of functions and classes, while in C/C++ a compiled library is the corresponding binary code of a bunch of functions and classes. In Linux, this binary code is probably in the [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and thus you can read about how the ELF format works to understand how a library "looks inside" in binary format (at least in Linux).

As a final note, the "entry point" does not necessarily need to be the main function. This is just the convention if you don't specify otherwise. [In this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/executing-main-in-c-behind-the-scene/) there is an example of compiling with gcc and specifying a different entry point for the executable. When you compile your code what you get is either a library of an executable depending on how you compiled.